# Android - AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenIdAWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am developing a service in Android that sends reports to an AWS queue.
I use what is available in the SDK but to no avail.
I have setup an user in IAM that has full access to the defined queue.
The queue allows all users to do all operations.
I am using the key and secret of this user in Android like this:

```
BasicAWSCredentials m_awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(PREF_AWS_ACCESSKEY,PREF_AWS_SECRETKEY);

AmazonSQSClient m_sqs_client= new AmazonSQSClient(m_awsCredentials);
Strting m_queue_url = m_sqs_client.getQueueUrl(m_queue_name).getQueueUrl();
m_sqs_client.sendMessage(m_queue_url, report);
```

Tried the second version of sendMessage like:

```
 SendMessageRequest send_msg_request = new SendMessageRequest()
                .withQueueUrl(m_queue_url)
                .withMessageBody(report)
                .withDelaySeconds(0);
 m_sqs_client.sendMessage(send_msg_request);
```

where report is a json string message to be sent.

And I always get:

```
Exception :The security token included in the request is invalid. 
(Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId;
```

As side test I have an app running in windows (C#) which uses exact the same credentials to access the S3 in that user account and that one has no problems accessing S3 data.

I also access S3 from the same Android app as above using the same keys and that one also works. Only the SQS complains.

I did check all questions/responses in stack overflow and got no answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging into SDK I found the answer. Setting the region on the client:

```
Region m_region=Region.getRegion(regionAWSName);
m_sqs_client.setRegion(m_region);
```

The next issue faced was that the region name which was set by an Windows app didn't match the canonical name expected by the Region class. If it helps anyone this is those are conversion making apps work together:

JAVA:

```
public static String convertRegionEndpoint(String endpointStr)
{
    switch (endpointStr)
    {
        case "US East (N. Virginia)":         return "us-east-1";
        case "US East (Ohio)":                return "us-east-2";
        case "US West (N. California)":       return "us-west-1";
        case "US West (Oregon)":              return "us-west-2";
        case "Africa (Cape Town)":            return "af-south-1";
        case "Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)":      return "ap-east-1";
        case "Asia Pacific (Mumbai)":         return "ap-south-1";
        case "Asia Pacific (Osaka)":          return "ap-northeast-3";
        case "Asia Pacific (Seoul)":          return "ap-northeast-2";
        case "Asia Pacific (Singapore)":      return "ap-southeast-1";
        case "Asia Pacific (Sydney)":         return "ap-southeast-2";
        case "Asia Pacific (Tokyo)":          return "ap-northeast-1";
        case "Canada (Central)":              return "ca-central-1";
        case "Europe (Frankfurt)":            return "eu-central-1";
        case "Europe (Ireland)":              return "eu-west-1";
        case "Europe (London)":               return "eu-west-2";
        case "Europe (Milan)":                return "eu-south-1";
        case "Europe (Paris)":                return "eu-west-3";
        case "Europe (Stockholm)":            return "eu-north-1";
        case "Middle East (Bahrain)":         return "me-south-1";
        case "South America (São Paulo)":     return "sa-east-1";
        default:                r             return "UNKNOWN";

    }
```

WINDOWS (C#)

```
RegionEndpoint convertRegionEndpoint(string endpointStr)
    {
        switch (endpointStr)
        {
            case "Africa (Cape Town)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.AFSouth1;
            case "Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APEast1;
            case "Asia Pacific (Tokyo)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1;
            case "Asia Pacific (Seoul)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APNortheast2;
            case "Asia Pacific (Osaka-Local)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APNortheast3;
            case "Asia Pacific (Mumbai)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSouth1;
            case "Asia Pacific (Singapore)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1;
            case "Asia Pacific (Sydney)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2;
            case "Canada (Central)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.CACentral1;
            case "China (Beijing)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.CNNorth1;
            case "China (Ningxia)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.CNNorthWest1;
            case "EU Central (Frankfurt)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;
            case "EU North (Stockholm)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUNorth1;
            case "Europe (Milan)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUSouth1;
            case "EU West (Ireland)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;
            case "EU West (London)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2;
            case "EU West (Paris)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest3;
            case "Middle East (Bahrain)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.MESouth1;
            case "South America (Sao Paulo)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.SAEast1;
            case "US East (Virginia)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
            case "US East (Ohio)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2;
            case "US GovCloud East (Virginia)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USGovCloudEast1;
            case "US GovCloud West (Oregon)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USGovCloudWest1;
            case "US West (N. California)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1;
            case "US West (Oregon)": return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2;
            default: return Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2;

        }
    }
```